# Tailwind doesn't compile classes in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

My API returns a list of assets, each with its own attributes, and these attributes allow me to customize the UI of my list.

I would like to customize the background for each of the items in my list, based on these attributes.

This is a minimalist component :

```js
export function AssetCard({ asset, children }: AssetCardProps) {
  // retrieve the appropriate color based on the asset attribute
  const color = useAssetColor(asset)

  <div
    className={cn(
      "relative", color ?? "bg-muted", className
    )}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
}
```

This is my custom hook :

```js
const COLORS: Record<string, string> = {
  purple: "!bg-gradient-to-r !from-[#E526FC]/20 !to-[#2B4FFC]/20",
  green: "!bg-gradient-to-r !from-[#64FF9E]/20 !to-[#2B6F85]/20",
  yellow: "!bg-gradient-to-r !from-[#FFE4B7]/20 !to-[#B1B437]/20",
}

export const useAssetColor = (
  asset: AssetWithTradeData
) => {
  const colorAttribute = asset.metadata.attributes?.find(
    (attr: { trait_type: string }) => attr.trait_type === "Scarcity"
  )?.value as string | null | undefined

  const color = useMemo(() => {
    return colorAttribute ? COLORS[colorAttribute] : null
  }, [colorAttribute])

  return color
}
```

When the value is **purple**, I should inject the **purple** classes into a div.

In reality, everything works.

In the inspector, my divs look like this:

`<div class="relative !bg-gradient-to-r !from-[#E526FC]/20 !to-[#2B4FFC]/20">...</div>`

Yet, these classes don't seem to exist, as if they weren't "compiled" by tailwind.

When I move the logic of the hook directly into my component, **it works perfectly**.

I remember that tailwind didn't like conditional rendering. Maybe the same with hooks?

Comment: Why a hook over a simple function? `useMemo` is for expensive operations, it's not going to improve a key-value lookup ^^

Comment: You're right, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the custom hook may be in a separate file from the component. Consider checking the file that the custom hook is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration. You can read more about [`content` configuration in the Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).

Comment: That was it. My utils folder was not specified in the tailwind conf. Thanks !